# integration of velocity distribution f(v)

Tags: star-cluster

The fraction $f$ of stars with velocities $v$ between $v$ and $v + \Delta v$ is given by
\begin{equation}
f(v) \propto 4\pi v^2 e^{-\frac{m \phi(\vec{x}) + \frac{mv^2}{2}}{k_\mathrm{B}T}}
\end{equation}

What does it mean when we integrate this function, please? I integrated from 0 to 1000 and obtained about 60 000. Is it the total number of stars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to divide 60,000 by the integral of this function from zero to infinity. That will then give you the *fraction* of stars with a velocity  (I think it is probably speed, not velocity?) between 0 and 1000.

The reason you need to do this is that the distribution function as you have given is given as a proportionality and does not have the correct normalisation constant at the front.

Comment: Thank you very much.